# "does that". it's hard to listen (british accent)

Tags: listening

[**linked mp3 file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K7n8xgoLp6F3YudbOhtweq3PtMw5FV30/view?usp=drive_link)

this linked mp3 file is very short dialogue.

the script is...
A : **Does that** sound good?
B : Yes

"**Does that**" is hard to listen.

"does that" sounds like **"/dʌt/"** to me.

there are 3 possibilities.

1. "/dʌz ðæt/" is said clearly and I can't listen correctly.
2. there is something reduced, something like "what's that => wassat"
3. etc

any advice?

thx for reading.

cf.
[**the original mov link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVdg9vbFoso&t=20s)

Comment: Are you sure the clip isn't cut off at the start? He could be saying just "That sound good?", though.

Comment: He is saying 'That sound good?'. Where is the 'script'?

Comment: When you wrote 'script' I think you meant 'YouTube subtitles', which are not the same thing, and are notoriously unreliable guides to the words actually spoken. They may be automatically machine generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very common in normal speech that in a phrase like "Does that sound good?" the first word is swallowed so it barely exists, coming out more like "dz". Sometimes it is just voiced as a z, or omitted completely. It can also be merged with the second word. So it can be "Dz that sound good?"; "Zat sound good?"; "That sound good?". This isn't deliberate, it's a side-effect of talking quickly. The same person can pronounce the word fully, or partly, or not at all - depending on circumstances.

The meaning is the same in every case. Trying to distinguish exactly what is said is irrelevant unless you are studying pronunciation. And no, it's not a problem with your hearing.

Comment: If somebody subtitled the conversation from the clip they would probably write it in full: "Does that sound good?". That would best convey the meaning, which is usually the purpose of subtitles. I have the same problem with Spanish, which I am learning. Native speakers sometimes run words together.

Comment: @dotoryjub - casual contractions like 'wanna', 'gonna', etc have no place in the level of writing expected on here.